# OpenLayers 3 show different highlight style based on layer type

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a map with two layers. One layers display points (circles) and another layer display an icon on the map.

I would like two have to highlight styles so that when then user clicks on a feature it shows the correct highlight style based on the layer type.

Right now I have created two highlight styles. I also have a 'select' event which selects the feature clicked. When I click on a new feature the "old" feature does not remove the highlight style.

So far I have this:

```
var highlightOne = function () {
    var scaleRadius = map.getView().getZoom() >= 7 ? 15 : 5;
    return [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: scaleRadius,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#fff'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#658acf',
                width: 2
            })
        }),

        zIndex: 1
    })]
}
var highlightTwo = function () {
    var scaleRadius = map.getView().getZoom() >= 7 ? 15 : 15;
    return [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
            radius: scaleRadius,
            points: 4,
            rotation: 0.8,
            rotateWithView: true,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#fff'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#658acf',
                width: 2
            })
        }),

        zIndex: 1
    })]
}

var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
    style: highlightStyle
});

selectInteraction.on('select', function (e) {
    var selected = e.selected,
    deselected = e.deselected;

    if (selected.length) // Selected feature
    {
        selected.forEach(function (feature) {
            // Get the layer name to apply custom highlight style
            if (feature.getLayer().get('name') == "layerone")
            {
                feature.setStyle(highlightTwo)
            } else {
                feature.setStyle(highlightOne)
            }
        })
    } else {
        deselected.forEach(function (feature) {
            // Remove highlight from the other features
            feature.setStyle(null)
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Your condition for the block that resets the style looks wrong. When do you want to reset the styles? When `e.deselected.length > 0`?

Comment: I want to reset the styles once the user has click out of the feature. Is there a select.unset()?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to avoid setting the styles on the features when setting a temporary display style (as you do with the select interaction). Setting style functions on layers or interactions are not only more memory efficient, it's also takes any responsability of unsetting the style from you.

I would suggest that you look at a solution like

```
var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
    style: function(feature, resolution){
        if (feature.getLayer().get('name') == "layerone") {
            return highlightTwo()
        } else {
            return highlightOne()
        }
    }
});
```

As a side note, I would suggest using the resolution parameter to the style function rather than polling the map for the current zoom level. When setting a style on the feature with a radius based on the current zoom level, the style will not update when zooming in or out.

Comment: feature.getLayer() did not work for me error message says getLayer() is not a function.